# Create TypeScript definition files with angular-cli

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I want to create TypeScript definition files with angular-cli. In the `angular-cli.json` there is specified the `tsconfig` file, but when I modify `"declaration"` to `true` in the `tsconfig.json`, it's not working.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

`angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "name": "app-name"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "assets/fix/ubuntu.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)",
    "../node_modules/ubuntu-fontface/fonts/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"
  ],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "sass",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

I also don't got the `out-tsc` directory. Running `ntsc -p` I got the definition files, but I want to create with angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your tsconfig is that you cant set `es6` as module while targetting
`es5`.

Check [compiler options here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Try `CommonJS` in module or `es2015` as target depending on your project.

Comment: Hope the answer solves your declaration issue though